# Get Server time Not Local time

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

this is my php script to show server time but this is showing local machine time 
can any one help me where i am doing wrong ? 
i have 1 other script ffor server time but that show NaN so i have to make it work but i cant understand what is wrong in this and why that is not showing server time

THIS IS MY PHP SCRIPT

```
   SDate.handle(<?php echo time() * 1000?>);
   setInterval(function () {
          var element = document.getElementById("time");
          if (!element) return;
          function lz(v) {
                 return v < 10 ? "0" + v : v;
          }
          var time = SDate.now();
          element.innerHTML = '<b>Server Time</b> ' +
                  lz(time.getHours()) + ":" +
                 lz(time.getMinutes()) + ":" +
                 lz(time.getSeconds())
          ;
   },1000);
```

This Is my Java Script

```
var SDate = new function() {
this.offset = 0;
this.handle = function (UTC) {
    if (!isFinite(UTC)) return;
    this.offset = UTC - new Date().valueOf();
    if (Math.abs(this.offset) < 60000) this.offset = 0;
}
this.now = function () {
    var time = new Date();
    time.setTime(this.offset + time.getTime());
    return time;
}
```

}();

please help me guys 
sorry for bad English
i Am Using Ubuntu Lamp-Server

Comment: It looks like your "PHP SCRIPT" is actually just JavaScript that with a tiny bit of PHP mixed in. You pass the server's time to the JS in the first line, but later on, you end up using the JS function `SDate.now()`, which apparently gets the local machine's time. Any function that runs in JavaScript will get the local time and not the server time.

Comment: Thanks Buddy Your

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's time() function in PHP...